# SQL Server Database Error asp.net

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

Two tables and two procedures in my machine using SQL Server 2008 Express in my VS 2010. The problem is my database does not on the lab machine and it keeps showing my an error saying:

> The database cannot be opened because it is version 661.This server supports version 655 and earlier.

My question is, I need to  activate my database in SQL Server whether home or in the lab, i.e a folder of my data can be initiated, saved in my USB and run on the lab machine as well as home! Is there anyway I can do that and how?!

Update: how do I make a copy of the data from the SQL Server 2008 R2 database to a 655 version DB?

Thank you

Comment: What is unclear in the error message?

Comment: How do I make a copy of the data from the R2 DB to a 655 version DB?

Comment: You **CANNOT** go back from a newer database version (661 = SQL Server **2008 R2**) to an earlier one (655 = SQL Server **2008**). There's no way, no undocumented hack, no trick, no magic to achieve this - it just **isn't possible** - period. You need to use the same version of SQL Server on all systems

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to attach a SQL Server 2008 R2 database (version 661) to a SQL Server 2008 Express instance (version 655). You cannot downgrade your DB. You will need to either upgrade your instance to SQL Server 2008 R2 - or copy the data from the R2 DB to a 655 version DB. I would upgrade your instance if I were you.

Comment: Yes, How do I make a copy of data from the R2 DB to a 655 version DB. This is the core of my QUESTION

Comment: You will need to export the data an import it. There are numerous ways to do this. You will need an SQL Server 2008 R2 intance to load the database into and export it. There is a SQL Server Import Export Wizard you can use. If you can have both instances running, you can transfer the data between both databases. You can install the Management Studio Express and it will have the Import Export Wizard. Have fun!

Comment: It sounds so complicated as its ! Is there anyway easier than this?

Comment: Just upgrade the SQL 2008 instance to SQL 2008 R2.